# Improve search string in EditText

Tags: android, string, search, android-edittext

I need to improve my system search strings of my `EditText`. Currently I have this example:

String to search -> **Museo Nacional del Prado**

If I search these strings they are found:

- Museo Nacional
- Prado

If I search this string it is not found:

- Museo del Prado

How I can debug my code to find `Museo del Prado`? thanks

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    filterArray.clear();
    searchString = edittextBuscar.getText().toString().trim();

    String cadenaBuscar = reemplazarCaracteres(searchString);

    if (items.size() > 0 && cadenaBuscar.length() > 0) {

        for (Items name : items) {

            String cadenaItem = reemplazarCaracteres(name.getNombre());

            if (cadenaItem.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(cadenaBuscar.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()))) {

                filterArray.add(name);
            }
        }
        setAdapterToListview(filterArray);
    } else {
        filterArray.clear();
        setAdapterToListview(items);
    }
}

private static String reemplazarCaracteres(String cadena) {

    String original = "áàéèíìóòúùüÁÀÉÈÍÌÓÒÚÙÜñÑçÇ";
    String ascii = "aaeeiioouuuAAEEIIOOUUUnNcC";

    String cadenaLimpia = cadena;

    for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++) {

        cadenaLimpia = cadenaLimpia.replace(original.charAt(i), ascii.charAt(i));
    }
    return cadenaLimpia;
}
```

Comment: i think you should break your search string up into separate entities. Search for Museo, then search for del...then Prado. But a single string means you must match everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Museo Nacional del Prado** doesn't contains **Museo del Prado**

You need to search for all sub strings

```
String reference = "Museo Nacional del Prado";
String toSearch = "Museo del Prado";

StringTokenizer strk = new StringTokenizer(toSearch, " ", false);
boolean matchingResult = true;
while(strk.hasMoreTokens()){
    if(reference.contains(strk.nextToken()) == false){
        matchingResult = false;
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(matchingResult);
```

searching for "Museo del Prado" will then return true

Your can add this method :

```
private boolean match(String reference, String toSearch){
    StringTokenizer strk = new StringTokenizer(toSearch, " ", false);
    boolean matchingResult = true;
    while(strk.hasMoreTokens()){
        if(reference.contains(strk.nextToken()) == false){
        matchingResult = false;
        break;
    }
    return matchingResult;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
String cadenaItem = reemplazarCaracteres(name.getNombre());

if(match(cadenaItem.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()), cadenaBuscar.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())     )) {
    filterArray.add(name);
}
```